# Qual è il senso di "tenere" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Prendiluna*, di Stefano Benni, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> – Cosa sapete voi umani della morte? Ascoltami. Hai otto giorni, come negli antichi calendari. Devi consegnare i Diecimici, ognuno a una persona degna e buona. Poi porterai la lista al Diobono, ti dirò io dove. Se troverai queste dieci persone, il mondo sarà salvo. Se no sarà la fine di tutto, e il mondo verrà annientato, e stavolta non ci sarà nuovo carbonio o Dna che **tenga**, finito, consummatum est, finished, vorbei, hatanka, piùmiau...

Non capisco qual è il senso del verbo "tenere" in questo brano. L'ho cercato in alcuni dizionari, ma ci sono tante accezioni che non riesco a capacitarmi di quale sia quella che corrisponda all'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio sopra citato. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Credo [8,b](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tenere/). La risposta di egreg ti punta sulla locuzione che è venuta in mente anche a me _"Non c'è santo che tenga"_, con il significato _non ci sarà riemedio (pezza) in grado di tenere,_ senza cedere ed evitare che si verifichi una eventualità non desiderata e ritenuta ineluttabile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La costruzione “succederà *x*, non c'è *y* che tenga” significa che per quanto *y* sia abbondante forte disponibile e simili, l'evento *x* si verificherà comunque.

Probabilmente l'espressione originale è “[non c'è santi che tengano](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/santo)” o “non c'è santo che tenga”: nemmeno l'intervento di uno o più santi può evitare l'evento *x*. A “santo” si può sostituire più o meno qualsiasi cosa, magari più connessa con l'evento *x*.

Si sente anche spesso “non c'è scusa che tenga”, ma è una faccenda diversa: qui “tenga” è usato come sinonimo di “regga”.